# What is the difference between Raising Exceptions vs Throwing Exceptions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

Ruby has two different exceptions mechanisms: Throw/Catch and Raise/Rescue.

Why do we have two?

When should you use one and not the other?

Comment: “getting out of nested loops” is a common need in many programming languages. Besides the `goto` in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/goto)/[C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) as @docwhat has mentioned, Java has [labeled break and continue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). (Python also has a [rejected proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/) for this.)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I think http://hasno.info/ruby-gotchas-and-caveats has a decent explanation of the difference:

> catch/throw are not the same as raise/rescue. catch/throw allows you to quickly exit blocks back to a point where a catch is defined for a specific symbol, raise rescue is the real exception handling stuff involving the Exception object.

Comment: Curious to know... Reading this from an iPad, so can't test them in 1.9, but some of those gotchas are no longer valid in recent ruby versions, right?

Comment: Also worth knowing: `raise` is very expensive. `throw` is not. Think of `throw` as using `goto` to get out of a loop.

Comment: @Denis Which gotchas are you referring to?

Comment: The link is broken!

Comment: See [*ruby catch-throw and efficiency*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484004/ruby-catch-throw-and-efficiency) to understand more about the performance difference.

Comment: @docwhat what do you mean by "very expensive" Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `raise` has to keep track of the frames (contexts) for its backtrace. `throw` is like `goto` and keeps no additional state.

Answer (score 145):

- `raise`, `fail`, `rescue`, and `ensure` handle **errors**, also known as **exceptions**
- `throw`, `catch`, `break`, and `next` are **control flow**

> Unlike in other
> languages, Ruby’s throw and catch are not used for exceptions.
> Instead, they provide a way to terminate execution early when no
> further work is needed.
> (Grimm, 2011)

Terminating a single level of control flow, like a `while` loop, can be done with `break`.  Terminating many levels of control flow, like a nested loop, can be done with `throw`.

> While the exception mechanism of raise and rescue is great for abandoning execution when things go wrong, it's sometimes nice to be able to jump out of some deeply nested construct during normal processing. This is where catch and throw come in handy.
> (Thomas and Hunt, 2001)

#### References

1. Grimm. "Throw, Catch, Raise, Rescue… I’m so Confused!" RubyLearning Blog. N.p., 11 July 2011. Web. 1 Jan. 2012. http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/07/12/throw-catch-raise-rescue--im-so-confused/.
2. Thomas, Hunt. "Programming Ruby." : The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide. N.p., 2001. Web. 29 Sept. 2015. http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html.

Comment: Avdi does _not_ look like he sounds in podcasts.

Comment: The Ruby Learning link doesn't seem to work. Here's another blog post that discusses the differences: http://danielchangnyc.github.io/blog/2013/10/23/throw-raise/

Comment: Funny, rubylearning.com thinks that Avdi's article [is still there](http://rubylearning.com/blog/author/avdigrimm/).   I guess that's why we copy stuff over to SO, so it won't be lost!

Answer (score 23):

https://coderwall.com/p/lhkkug/don-t-confuse-ruby-s-throw-statement-with-raise offers an excellent explanation that I doubt I can improve on. To summarize, nicking some code samples from the blog post as I go:

1. `raise`/`rescue` are the closest analogues to the `throw`/`catch` construct you're familiar with from other languages (or to Python's `raise`/`except`). If you've encountered an error condition and you would `throw` over it in another language, you should `raise` in Ruby.
2. Ruby's `throw`/`catch` lets you break execution and climb up the stack looking for a `catch` (like `raise`/`rescue` does), but isn't really meant for error conditions. It should be used rarely, and is there just for when the "walk up the stack until you find a corresponding `catch`" behaviour makes sense for an algorithm you're writing but it wouldn't make sense to think of the `throw` as corresponding to an error condition.

   [What is catch and throw used for in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716801/what-is-catch-and-throw-used-for-in-ruby/) offers some suggestions on nice uses of the `throw`/`catch` construct.

The concrete behavioural differences between them include:

- `rescue Foo` will rescue instances of `Foo` including subclasses of `Foo`. `catch(foo)` will only catch *the same object, `Foo`*. Not only can you not pass `catch` a class name to catch instances of it, but it won't even do equality comparisons. For instance

  ```
  catch("foo") do
    throw "foo"
  end
  ```

  will give you an `UncaughtThrowError: uncaught throw "foo"` (or an `ArgumentError` in versions of Ruby prior to 2.2)
- Multiple rescue clauses can be listed...

  ```
  begin
    do_something_error_prone
  rescue AParticularKindOfError
    # Insert heroism here.
  rescue
    write_to_error_log
    raise
  end
  ```

  while multiple `catch`es need to be nested...

  ```
  catch :foo do
    catch :bar do
      do_something_that_can_throw_foo_or_bar
    end
  end
  ```
- A bare `rescue` is equivalent to `rescue StandardError` and is an idiomatic construct. A "bare `catch`", like `catch() {throw :foo}`, will never catch anything and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Good explanation but begs the question, why on earth would they design raise in ruby = throw in other language. and then also include throw but it != throw in other languages. I can't see their original logic there

Comment: @wired00 *(Shrug.)* I agree that it seems pretty eccentric compared to other popular languages today.

Comment: @wired00: It has been called "raising" an exception ever since the very first experiments with structured error handling in the 1960s, it is called "raising" an exception in the seminal articles that invented the modern form of exception handling, it is called "raising" an exception in Lisps and Smalltalks, which were some of the main inspirations for Ruby, and it is called "raising" an exception or "raising" an interrupt in hardware, where the concept existed even before the concept of a "programming language" existed. The question should rather be: why did those other languages change that?

Comment: @MarkAmery: Remember that many of those "other popular languages" are *younger* than Ruby or at least contemporary. So, the question should rather be: why did those other languages not follow Ruby (and Smalltalk and Lisp and hardware and the literature).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Interesting - you inspired me to do a little historical research. C++ had the notion of "throwing" an exception years before Ruby came along, and per https://english.stackexchange.com/a/449209/73974 the term actually goes back to the 70s... so I think we still get to criticise Ruby for taking established terminology and using it to mean something completely different.