# What is catch and throw used for in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In most other languages, the catch and throw statements do what the begin, rescue, and raise statements do in Ruby. I know the you can do this with these two statements:

```
catch :done do
  puts "I'm done."
end
```

and

```
if some_condition
  throw :done
end
```

But what is this useful for? Can somebody please give me an example of what catch and throw statements are used for in Ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021/what-is-the-differance-between-raising-exceptions-vs-throwing-exceptions-in-ruby

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use this to break out of nested loops.

```
INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0
catch (:done) do
  1.upto(INFINITY) do |i|
    1.upto(INFINITY) do |j|
      if some_condition
        throw :done
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you had used a break statement above, it would have broken out of the inner loop. But if you want to break out of the nested loop, then this catch/throw would be really helpful. I have used it [here](http://tech.bragboy.com/2010/08/project-euler-find-smallest-positive.html) to solve one of the Euler problems.

Answer (score 23):

I have been looking for a good example for a while, until I met Sinatra.
IMHO, Sinatra exposes a very interesting example usage for `catch`.

In Sinatra you can [immediately terminate a request](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro) at any time using `halt`.

```
halt
```

You can also specify the status when halting...

```
halt 410
```

Or the body...

```
halt 'this will be the body'
```

Or both...

```
halt 401, 'go away!'
```

The halt method is [implemented using throw](http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L436-439).

```
def halt(*response)
  response = response.first if response.length == 1
  throw :halt, response
end
```

and [caught by](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1066) the `invoke` method.

There are several uses of `:halt` in Sinatra. You can read the source code for more examples.

Comment: Throw it's a more elegant way to use an exception-like system as a control flow.

Comment: @jsz for one, it's much faster—the stack frame does not have to be carried along the "thrown symbol", and no object is created. Lightweight nonlinear flow control.

Comment: @mezis yes modern GOTO

Answer (score 4):

When writing recursive algorithms that act on nested data structures using recursive functions, you can use `throw` similarly to how you would use a `break` or early `return`  when writing iterative algorithms that act on flat data using `for` loops.

For example, suppose that you have a list of positive integers and you want (for some reason) to write a function that will return true if either of the following conditions are met:

- The sum of all elements in the list is greater than 100
- Some element in the list if equal to 5

Let's say also that you always want to perform this check in a single, short-circuiting pass over the list, rather than doing a `reduce` call to get the sum and a separate `any?` call to look for fives.

You'd probably write some code a bit like this (indeed, you probably HAVE written code like this in some language at some point in your life):

```
def test(list)
  sum = 0
  for i in list
    sum += i
    if i == 5 || sum > 100
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

In most languages, there is no clean equivalent for breaking out of a recursive algorithm that uses a recursive function. In Ruby, though, there is! Suppose that, instead of having a list and wanting to check if its elements contain a five or sum to over 100, you have a *tree* and want to check if its *leaves* contain a five or sum to over 100, while short-circuiting and returning as soon as you know the answer.

You can do this elegantly with `throw`/`catch`, like this:

```
def _test_recurse(sum_so_far, node)
  if node.is_a? InternalNode
    for child_node in node.children
      sum_so_far = _test_recurse(sum_so_far, child_node)
    end
    return sum_so_far
  else # node.is_a? Leaf
    sum_so_far += node.value
    if node.value == 5
      throw :passes_test
    elsif sum_so_far > 100
      throw :passes_test
    else
      return sum_so_far
    end
  end
end

def test(tree)            
  catch (:passes_test) do
    _test_recurse(0, tree)
    return false
  end
  return true
end
```

The `throw :passes_test` here acts a bit like a `break`; it lets you jump out of your whole call stack below the outermost `_test` call. In other languages, you could do this either by abusing exceptions for this purpose or by using some return code to tell the recursive function to stop recursing, but this is more direct and simpler.

Comment: This answer is fascinating/compelling since using `throw` actually simplified the code.  In contrast, the accepted answer just uses `throw` as a more esoteric version of `return` without gaining anything from it.