# Why can't I catch the test exception in the "caller" method?

Tags: ruby, exception

I don't understand why this code is not working properly:

```
def test
  raise Exception.new 'error'
end

def caller
  begin
    test
  rescue =>e
     puts e.message
  end
end

caller
```

I want to catch the test exception in the `caller` method, but it seems that the `caller` method is not catching anything.

Comment: fwiw, when performing a `begin rescue end` within a method, you can drop the `begin` and `end`. Saves a few lines of code i.e. `def caller;test;rescue Exception=>e;puts e.message;end`

Comment: Just as a stylistic thing, you don't need to use `new` when raising an exception. `raise Exception, 'error'` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan beat me to it, but...

When you use the `=> var` syntax with `exception`, you must specify what kind of exception you want to rescue. The base class for all exceptions is Exception, so it will work if you change that to `rescue Exception => e`. Also, when what you're rescuing from is the entire body of a method, you don't need an explicit begin...end block...

```
def test
  raise Exception.new 'error'
end

def caller
  test
rescue Exception =>e
  puts e.message
end

caller()
```

Comment: Again, this is not necessarily true. You probably **don't** want to `rescue Exception => e` since you are going to catch lower-level exceptions than your program is able to deal with.

Comment: Of course, I should have mentioned that rescuing `Exception` is not usually a good thing to do. Since, in this case, `Exception` is what is being raised, however, ...

Answer (score 6):

The reason your code doesn't work is because `rescue` without an explicitly stated exception type only catches `StandardError`, which is a subclass of `Exception`. Since you're raising `Exception`, which is higher than `StandardError`, your `rescue` doesn't catch it.

Generally you want to use more specific exceptions, and you almost never need to use `Exception` over `StandardError`.

This, for example, works fine:

```
begin
  raise StandardError.new 'Uh-oh!'
rescue => e
  p e.message
end

#=> Uh-oh!
```

Comment: "Generally you want to use more specific exceptions", agreed. The added granularity helps when dealing with flow-control in "battle-conditions".

Answer (score 2):

You should specify what kind of exceptions you'd like to `rescue`. Try

```
  rescue Exception => e
```

Comment: Thanks this worked well. I can't understand the difference between the throw and the raise statement...

Comment: Not necessarily…see my answer. It's generally a bad idea to `rescue Exception => e` because you're probably catching lower-level exceptions than your application is ready to handle.

Comment: @BenD, throw/raise differences [were covered in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021/what-is-the-difference-between-raising-exceptions-vs-throwing-exceptions-in-ruby).

Comment: I agree with coreyward: The better advise is not to raise an `Exception` in the first place but using more specific error classes like `StandardError`