# ruby catch-throw and efficiency

Tags: ruby, performance, try-catch, throw, control-structure

`catch` in Ruby is meant to jump out of deeply nested code. In Java e.g. it is possible to achieve the same with Java's `try-catch` meant for handling exceptions, it is however considered poor solution and is also very inefficient. In Ruby for handling exceptions we have `begin-raise-rescue` and I assume it is also to expensive to use it for other tasks.

Is Ruby's `catch-throw` really a more efficient solution then `begin-raise-rescue` or are there any other reasons to use it to break nested blocks instead of `begin-raise-rescue`?

Comment: If you post some ruby examples of the control structures you are asking about, it may be more clear what you mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to being the "correct" way to get out of control structures, `catch-throw` is also  significantly faster(10 times as fast in my testing).  Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4122195) for my code and results.

Comment: Thanks! The benchmark really clears the issue (in my case it is almost 15 times!). Should catch-throw be considered a structural style of programing -- a better practice then despised goto?

Comment: It's your design requires catch-throw, there is probably a better design. That being said, there are definitely edge cases where catch throw make a lot of sense, especially in gem develop where you don't know how the end user will use it.

Comment: Thanks for all explanations!

Answer (score 8):

[Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484425/541862) is correct. I want to add more information about `catch-throw` and `raise-rescue`.

`catch-throw` is used for flow control whereas `raise-rescue` is used for exception/error handling. The different is: `backtrace` is not needed for `catch-throw` (flow control). Trust me, the main reason causes `raise-rescue` runs slow than `catch-throw` 10 times in [Josh's gist](https://gist.github.com/4122195) is `raise-rescue` takes a lot time to create `backtrace` object.

If you want to `raise` without backtrace, use syntax:

```
raise <type>, <message>, <backtrace>
```

Checkout [my gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobdam/5864997). `raise without backtrace` is much faster than `raise with backtrace`.

**April 2016 Update:**

I've updated [my gist](https://gist.github.com/jacobdam/5864997):

- Fixed "break" test
- Added benchmark tests results for newer ruby version 2.1.8, 2.2.4, 2.3.0