# How to view the call stack when an object is thrown in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

The warden gem uses `throw` and `catch` functions to handle control flow. This makes it super hard to debug authentication systems, especially in `devise` where the gem `throw`s the `:warden` symbol and the `warden` gem `catch`es it.

I my program, I have a function that (indirectly) throws a `:warden` symbol, but I don't know what is the exact call site of the`throw` function. Is there a way to find it?

It seems that we cannot use the `TracePoint` class because it only supports `raise` events.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021/what-is-the-difference-between-raising-exceptions-vs-throwing-exceptions-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get something working using `TracePoint` and the fact that `throw` is a c language routine by trapping `c_call`:

```
TracePoint.new(:c_call) do |trace|
  if trace.method_id == :throw
    p [trace.path, trace.lineno]
  end
end
```

This will only get you where the call to `throw` was actually made, not a full stack trace of everything called up to that point, though you could play around with catching `:call` as well, and put something together that captures more information. As a quick example:

```
TracePoint.new(:call, :c_call) do |trace|
  if trace.event == :call || trace.method_id == :throw
    p [trace.method_id, trace.path, trace.lineno]
  end

  trace.disable if trace.method_id == :throw
end
```

Full example:

```
# might_throw_cont.rb
def might_throw_second
  throw :warden if rand(100) < 10

  might_throw_third
end

def might_throw_third
  throw :warden if rand(100) < 10

  might_throw_final
end

# example.rb
require './might_throw_cont'

def might_throw_first
  throw :warden if rand(100) < 10

  might_throw_second
end

def might_throw_final
  throw :warden if rand(100) < 10

  will_throw
end

def will_throw
  throw :warden
end

TracePoint.new(:call, :c_call) do |trace|
  if trace.event == :call || trace.method_id == :throw
    p [trace.method_id, trace.path, trace.lineno]
  end

  trace.disable if trace.method_id == :throw
end.enable do
  catch :warden do
    might_throw_first
  end

  puts "done"
end
```

Obviously, going to be hard to tell which method actually threw the symbol in this example. But running the example, a couple times I'll be able to see in the output (2 example runs):

```
# run 1
[:might_throw_first, "example.rb", 3]
[:might_throw_second, "/Users/simplelime/Documents/Ruby/might_throw_cont.rb", 1]
[:might_throw_third, "/Users/simplelime/Documents/Ruby/might_throw_cont.rb", 7]
[:might_throw_final, "example.rb", 9]
[:will_throw, "example.rb", 15]
[:throw, "example.rb", 16] # < only line you'll see if you trace only :c_call
done

# run 2
[:might_throw_first, "example.rb", 3]
[:throw, "example.rb", 4] # < only line you'll see if you trace only :c_call
done
```