# How to test that a piece of code that outputs to stderr while it raises an exception with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Consider the following methods:

```
  class MyClass
    def initialize
    end

    def will_throw
      print_message_to_stderr
      throw MyError
    end

    def print_message_to_stderr
      STDERR.puts 'Boom!'
    end
  end
```

I would like to test that `will_throw` does output a message to stderr first:

```
it 'outputs to stderr' do
  instance = MyClass.new

  expect { instance.will_throw }.to output('Boom!').to_stderr
end
```

This, however, doesn't succeed because the exception is thrown and the test suite blows up.

On the other hand, this is always green no matter what, and even when the test should fail:

```
it 'outputs to stderr' do
  instance = MyClass.new

  expect { instance.will_throw }.to output('Boom!').to_stderr
  rescue MyError
  end
end
```

How can I test this properly (using RSpec and plain Ruby)?

Answer (score 0):

[RSpec cannot catch `STDERR` nor `STDOUT`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher#output-to-stderr-matcher).

> Note: to_stdout and to_stderr work by temporarily replacing $stdout or $stderr, so they're not able to intercept stream output that explicitly uses STDOUT/STDERR or that uses a reference to $stdout/$stderr that was stored before the matcher is used.

`STDERR` is a constant and cannot (really *should* not) be changed. Simplest solution is to use `$stderr` instead. Better yet, use [`warn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Warning.html#method-i-warn) to make your intentions plain and allow warnings to be redirected.

Second problem is [`throw` and `raise` are not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021/what-is-the-difference-between-raising-exceptions-vs-throwing-exceptions-in-ruby#51037). `throw` is for control flow, `raise` is for exceptions. `throw` is like Ruby's `goto`. Use `raise` instead.

```
class MyClass
  # You don't need an empty initialize, it is inherited from Object.

  def will_raise
    print_message_to_stderr
    raise MyError
  end

  def print_message_to_stderr
    warn 'Boom!'
  end
end

class MyError < RuntimeError
end

RSpec.describe MyClass do
  it 'outputs to stderr and raises MyError' do
    instance = described_class.new

    expect {
      instance.will_raise
    }.to output("Boom!\n").to_stderr
    .and raise_error(MyError)
  end
end
```

Since your "warning" immediately precedes an exception, it's not really a warning, it's an error message. If you make it part of the Exception it will make handling errors much simpler. Do this by [providing a default message](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html#method-c-new). If the message is complex, you can override [`#message`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html#method-i-message).

Now the error and message can be caught and controlled as one unit. The code and tests are much simpler.

```
class MyClass
  def will_raise
    raise MyError
  end
end

class MyError < RuntimeError
  def initialize(message = "Boom!")
    super
  end
end

RSpec.describe MyClass do
  it 'raises MyError' do
    instance = described_class.new

    expect {
      instance.will_raise
    }.to raise_error(MyError, "Boom!")
  end
end
```

True warnings and informational messages are better done via [`Logger`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html). Logged messages are easier to control and redirect.

```
require 'logger'

class MyClass
  def logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new(STDERR)
  end

  def will_raise
    logger.warn("Lookout!")
    raise MyError
  end
end

class MyError < RuntimeError
  def initialize(message = "Boom!")
    super
  end
end
```

One generally does not test log messages, they're usually turned off during testing, but if you really wanted to you can check using a [message expectation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics/expecting-messages) and [`with` to specify its arguments](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments).

```
RSpec.describe MyClass do
  it 'raises MyError and logs a warning' do
    instance = described_class.new

    expect(instance.logger).to receive(:warn)
      .with("Lookout!")

    expect {
      instance.will_raise
    }.to raise_error(MyError, "Boom!")
  end
end
```

Generally you don't want to be trapping output if you can avoid it. You want to check method calls instead.

Comment: Thank you. That particular gem is a command line tool that is rather limited in scope. Would a logger still make more sense in that case? I took inspiration from other tools and they usually output their messages to stderr before closing. I wanted to avoid leaving the user confused with a ruby stack trace and error.

Comment: @springloaded Logger comes with Ruby, no reason not to use it. If nothing else Logger lets you easily provide verbosity levels.